# Fetch values from Object using map() operator and apply predicate

Tags: java, java-8, predicate

Please bear with me for silly question, I am new to Java8. I have to write the following code using lambda and apply the condition on the two attribute. I am able to fetch one and apply predicate on it.

```
for (EventTypePricingMapping eventTypePricingMapping : eventTypePricingMappings) {
        BigDecimal feePerRevenue = eventTypePricingMapping.getFeePerRevenue();
        if (feePerRevenue != null && feePerRevenue.intValue() < 0) {
            throw ExceptionHelper.badRequest("Fee Per Transaction can't be less than zero");
        }
        if (eventTypePricingMapping.getFeePerReg().intValue() < 0) {
            throw ExceptionHelper.badRequest("Fee Per Transaction can't be less than zero");
        }
    }
```

In the below code how can i fetch the value of `feePerRevenue` and apply predicate on it, as i have done for that `getfeePerReg` in the below code.

```
boolean isRegFeeInvalid = globalPricingRequests.stream()
                .map(GlobalPricingRequest::getEventTypePricingList)
                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .map(EventTypePricingMapping::getFeePerReg)
                .anyMatch(criteria);
```

My predicate is like as below :

```
Predicate<BigDecimal> criteria = value -> value != null && value.signum() < 0;
```

I have tried the below code as per suggestion but i am not able to fetch both the values in map() in the

```
boolean isRegFeeInvalid = globalPricingRequests.stream()
                .map(GlobalPricingRequest::getEventTypePricingList)
                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .map(EventTypePricingMapping::getFeePerReg,EventTypePricingMapping::getFeePerReg)
                .anyMatch(verifyFeePerRegAndFeePerRevenue());




private static boolean verifyFeePerRegAndFeePerRevenue(BigDecimal feePerReg, BigDecimal feePerRevenue) {
        Predicate<BigDecimal> criteria = value -> value != null && value.signum() < 0;
        return criteria.test(feePerReg) && criteria.test(feePerRevenue);
    }
```

How to fetch two values in line `map(EventTypePricingMapping::getFeePerReg,EventTypePricingMapping::getFeePerReg)` and pass them in anyMatch operator

Comment: I have updated the question please have a look at it again

Comment: do share your POJOs for people to reproduce or relate to what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? @IshantGaurav

Comment: Though the question isn't really clear. Ishant, just in case your requirement is to test the same condition for two attributes at different levels of a POJO. You can create a `Predicate<POJO>` where you can attain and test both those attributes(`&&`).

Comment: yup that's what i showed in case 2 @nullpointer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**map**

```
<R> Stream<R> map(Function<? super T,? extends R> mapper)
```

> Returns a stream consisting of the results of applying the given function to the elements of this stream.
>
> This is an intermediate operation.

So i will suggest to create two different `List`, one for `feePerReg` and another for `feePerRevenue`

**feePerReg**

```
List<BigDecimal> feeperReg =  globalPricingRequests.stream().flatMap(eventPrice->eventPrice.getEventTypePricingList().stream()).map(eventType->eventType.getFeePerReg()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**feePerRevenue**

```
List<BigDecimal> feePerRevenue = globalPricingRequests.stream().flatMap(eventPrice->eventPrice.getEventTypePricingList().stream()).map(eventType->eventType.getFeePerRevenue()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Predicate** Predicate to check for both lists

```
Predicate<BigDecimal> criteria = value -> value != null && value.signum() < 0;
```

**verifyFeePerRegAndFeePerRevenue** method that takes two `List<BigDecimal>` as arguments

```
private static boolean verifyFeePerRegAndFeePerRevenue(List<BigDecimal> feePerReg, List<BigDecimal> feePerRevenue) {
    Predicate<BigDecimal> criteria = value -> value != null && value.signum() < 0;
    return feePerReg.stream().anyMatch(criteria) && feePerRevenue.stream().anyMatch(criteria);
}
```

**Case 2**

Instead of two different `List`, you can have only one list with `eventTypePricingMapping` and `Predicate` condition on both `feePerReg` and `feePerRevenue`

**eventTypePricingMapping**

```
List<EventTypePricingMapping> result = globalPricingRequests.stream().flatMap(eventPrice->eventPrice.getEventTypePricingList().stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Predicate** Predicate to check for both

```
Predicate<EventTypePricingMapping> criteria = value -> value.getFeePerRevenue() != null && value.getFeePerReg()!= null && value.getFeePerRevenue() < 0 && value.getFeePerReg < 0;
```

**verifyFeePerRegAndFeePerRevenue** method takes `List<EventTypePricingMapping>` apply `Predicate` on list

```
private static boolean verifyFeePerRegAndFeePerRevenue(List<EventTypePricingMapping> price) {
    Predicate<EventTypePricingMapping> criteria = value -> value.getFeePerRevenue() != null && value.getFeePerReg()!= null && value.getFeePerRevenue() < 0 && value.getFeePerReg < 0;
    return price.stream().anyMatch(criteria);
}
```

Comment: case2 is what I believe is what OP is looking for

Comment: yup i agree with you, just to clarify i showed him different cases @nullpointer 